# How to do the Setting or importing or including the CSS Modules or files in the js file with React+Redux and Webpack

Tags: reactjs, redux, yeoman

How to do the Setting or importing or including the CSS Modules or files in the js file with React+Redux and Webpack.

### Note:

I have generated the file and folder structure for the react+redux app using the Yeoman

### folder structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl1p1.png)

### my files

## a. package.json

```
{
  "name": "DemoApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dev-server.js",
    "watch": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@comynli/store": "^0.1.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.3",
    "core-decorators": "^0.12.2",
    "history": "^1.9.0",
    "immutable": "^3.7.6",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.1.1",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "moment": "^2.12.0",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^0.14.8",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^0.14.8",
    "react-document-title": "^2.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.8",
    "react-notification-system": "^0.2.7",
    "react-redirect": "^1.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.4",
    "react-router": "^1.0.0",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^0.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.4.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.0.2",
    "redux-router": "^1.0.0-beta8",
    "redux-thunk": "^0.1.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.15",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^5.6.18",
    "babel-loader": "^5.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^1.1.0",
    "concurrently": "^0.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^0.8.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "http-proxy": "^1.11.2",
    "less": "^2.5.3",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^2.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.9.11",
    "webpack-combine-loaders": "^2.0.3",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

## b. webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var combineLoaders = require('webpack-combine-loaders');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './app/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env': { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development') } }),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['babel'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css)$/,
        exclude: /\.(useable|post)\.css/,
        loader: 'style!css'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(less)$/,
        exclude: /\.(useable|post)\.less/,
        loader: 'style!css!less'
      },
      {
        test: /\.post\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.useable\.css$/,
        loader: 'style/useable!css'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|png|jpg|gif|svg)/,
        loader: 'file!url'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
        loader: 'file!url'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }

    ],
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      }

    ]
  },

  postcss: [ require('autoprefixer')]
};
```

### c: dev-server.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var express = require('express');
var webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
var webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var _ = require("lodash");

var config = require('./webpack.config');
var proxyConfig = require('./proxy.config');

var app = new express();
var port = 8000;

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

var compiler = webpack(config);
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, { noInfo: true, publicPath: config.output.publicPath }));
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

app.use('/fonts', express.static(__dirname + '/fonts'));

app.use(function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(port, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.info("Listening on port %s. Open up http://localhost:%s/ in your browser.", port, port);
  }
});
```

---

## files are trigger as follows

```
dev-server.js --> index.html -> index.js --> common\main.component.js  file  --->
```

### main.component.js file contains

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

import styles from '../css/app';

class Main extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="bodycolor">
        <p>This text will be blue</p>
      </div>


  );
  }
}

export default Main
```

---

When I run the command ----

> npm run build

D:\VARA\CPKWebApp>npm run build

> CPKWebApp@0.1.0 build D:\VARA\CPKWebApp
>   webpack

Hash: a2151015fd7d5cc5be2b
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 4058ms
   [0] multi main 40 bytes {0} [built]
    + 573 hidden modules

ERROR in ./app/common/main.component.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../css/app in D:\VARA\CPKWebApp\app\common
 @ ./app/common/main.component.js 25:14-35

it is throwing the above error.

Please help on this...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyQm3.png)

---

When I run -->  npm run build it is

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `'../css/app'` from inside the `/app/common` directory. The two dots takes you back to the `app` directory. From there it is looking for a directory within `app` called `css` and then looking for `app` within `css` but I cannot see one in your structure.

Comment: In the folder structure there is one more directory name: css.  it is in the same level where the app folder resides. it(CSS folder) contains app.css file. still it is not refering to that. throwing same error

Comment: updated the folder structure. still facing the same issue.

Comment: try `../css/app.css`